# How to receive file_id through python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm making a Telegram bot using `python-telegram-bot`, and I need some way to receive voice messages. For that, I need to download them, and to do *that*, I have to get their `file_id`s. However, the `MessageHandler` handles... well, messages, and `Handler` gives me a `NotImplementedError`. Is there a way to get the `file_id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to download voice messages is to register a MessageHandler with a voice filter. The Docs provide more information on [Filters](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.ext.filters.html?highlight=Filters) and the [voice module](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.voice.html?highlight=voice).

```
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater

def voice_handler(bot, update):
    file = bot.getFile(update.message.voice.file_id)
    print ("file_id: " + str(update.message.voice.file_id))
    file.download('voice.ogg')

updater = Updater(token='TOKEN')
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.voice, voice_handler))
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is old but I was facing a problem with this in the latest version (12+)

So it appears that the bot- pass_user_data in the callback function is **deprecated** and from now on you should use context based callbacks.

> CallbackContext is an object that contains all the extra context
>   information regarding an Update, error or Job.

to the new style using CallbackContext:

```
def voice_handler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    file = context.bot.getFile(update.message.audio.file_id)
    file.download('./voice.ogg')
```

You can read more in the [Transition-guide-to-Version-12.0](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-12.0)

Answer (score 2):

In version 13+, you need to use update.message.**voice**.file_id instead of update.message.**audio**.file_id. So the code will be:

```
def voice_handler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    file = context.bot.getFile(update.message.voice.file_id)
    file.download('./voice.ogg')
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'll show you an example with a photo file, but it works for any file (you'll just need to change the parameters)

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
from telegram.ext.callbackcontext import CallbackContext
from telegram.update import Update

def start (update: Update, context: CallbackContext):

    # getting chat_id:
    chatID = update.effective_chat.id

    # sending the photo to discover its file_id:
    photo1 = context.bot.send_photo(chat_id=chatID, photo=open('photo1.jpg','rb'))
    photo1_fileID = photo1.photo[-1].file_id
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=('file_id photo1.jpg = ' + photo1_fileID))

def main():
    updater = Updater(token='TOKEN', use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```